# In honour to 2004

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

222444 is the smallest number that is divisible by 2004 and only contains the digits 2 and 4. What’s the next number that has the same properties?

Hint:The number is 11 digits long.

Comment: Besides, is this possible to solve without computers in a reasonable amount of time? I did so with a computer, and the answer doesn't seem to have a lot of patterns in it (but I may be wrong).

Comment: Its solvable by hands.

Comment: Could be 44444222244444, if we require a palindrome.

Comment: Not exactly....

Comment: 222444 = 2004 * 111, where 111 is a repunit. But the 11-digit one won't be so simple...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 42244442244 = 21080061 times 2004

To answer, consider the number

> 222...222 modulo 2004.
>  As the length increases, the remainder follows the pattern 2, 22, 222, 218, 178, -222, -214, -134, 666, 650, **490**...
>  The change to the remainder that we get from changing each of those 2's into a 4 likewise follows 2, 20, 200, -4, -40, -400, 8, 80, 800, -16, **-160**...
>  The problem of finding an 11-digit multiple of 2004 therefore reduces to finding a subset of the above remainders that sums to -490 (modulo 2004).
>  From the equation 2+20-40-400+8+80-160 = -490, we take the 2's with the remainders corresponding to the terms of the sum and turn them into 4's, yielding the answer.

Answer (score 7):

**Probable answer**:

> $42244442244=21080061\times2004$

Firstly

> There are no such numbers below $10^9$. On the other hand, $222444222444=222444\times1000001$ works.

Explanations:

> Let us consider a "divisibility by 1002" rule: a number $N=1000000x+1000y+z$ (so, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are 3-digit groups of $N$) has the same remainder modulo 1002 as $4x-2y+z$ (Proof: $(1000000x+1000y+z)-(4x-2y+z)=999996x+1002y$, and $999996=1000000-4=(1000+2)(1000-2)=1002\times998$. So, $999996x+1002y$ is divisible by 1002.)
>  Since $0\leqslant x\leqslant444$, $222\leqslant y\leqslant444$ and $222\leqslant z\leqslant444$, we have that $-222\leqslant4x-2y+z\leqslant1776$. We know that $z$ is divisible by 4 (because we actually want our number to be divisible by 2004, rather that 1002), so the whole thing $4x-2y+z$ must be divisible by 4 (because $y$ is even, containing only 2s and 4s).
>  So, $4x-2y+z=0$ ($0$ is the only number between $-222$ and $1776$ which is divisible by both $4$ and $1002$). We know that $z$ ends with $4$ (to be composed only of 2s and 4s and be divisible by 4). 
>
>      - If $x$ ends with 4, then $4x$ ends with 6, and $4x+z$ ends with 0, so $y$ must end with either 0 or 5, which is impossible.
>      - If $x$ ends with 2, then $4x$ ends with 8, and $4x+z$ ends with 2, so $y$ must end with either 1 or 6, which is again impossible. 
>
>  So, we came to a contradiction. So, no such number exists which is 7 to 9 digits long.

Note

> For the numbers up to 12 digits, we should consider and expression of the form $8x-4y+2z-t$, but there is a lot more possibilities. Trial and error gives the answer written above.

Answer (score 4):

Partial Answer on how to do it manually:

> We know for a fact that the next highest number will be $222444 \times \text{Natural Number}$.
>   Let that natural number be $...N_3N_2N_1$ (a number of arbitrary length as we don't know how long it will be)
>
> Let's do some elementary school multiplication!
>   We multiply $222444$ by $...N_3N_2N_1$
>
> ```
>        2  2  2  4  4  4
>   X  ..N6 N5 N4 N3 N2 N1
>   ----------------------
> ```

> Multiplying $N_1$ with $222444$ gives us the first line of the solution. Notice here that the unit's place of the final answer will be the unit's place of $N_1 \times 4$. The rest of the multiplication won't affect this place.
>   Since we want every number to be a $2$ or $4$, the possible values of $N_1$ are {$1,3,6,8$}.
>
> Let's continue the multiplication with the possible values.
>
> ```
>        2  2  2  4  4  4        2  2  2  4  4  4       2  2  2  4  4  4       2  2  2  4  4  4
>   X  ..N6 N5 N4 N3 N2 1    X ..N6 N5 N4 N3 N2 3   X ..N6 N5 N4 N3 N2 6   X ..N6 N5 N4 N3 N2 8
>   ----------------------  ---------------------  ---------------------   --------------------
>        2  2  2  4  4  4        6  6  7  3  3  2    1  3  3  4  6  6  4    1  7  7  9  5  5  2
>                       0                       0                      0                      0
> ```

> Notice that the second place digit in $N_1 = 3$ and $N_1 = 8$ is odd. This means that in the next step. (when we multiply with $N_2$) the overall ten's digit will be $\text{Odd} + N_2 \times 4$.
>   $N_2 \times 4$ is always even hence, $ \text{Odd+Even = Odd}$. In this case, the ten's digit cannot be either $4$ or $2$. Hence we eliminate the cases with $N_1=3$ and $N_1=8$
>   Matter of fact with every progression, (as we go up to higher $N$'s) every number with an odd digit at the $L_{th}$ place for the $N_L$ step can be discarded.
>   The next step then has to be done with both the remaining cases. We can say our question has branched.
>   The same process is recursively used, making a number of branches, as we have to do it for every subbranch that is a possible solution.
>
> Note: I admit this method is hard work. Even for the third step, it becomes very sophisticated to progress. And though we can develop some minor techniques to refine the process, I myself didn't have the courage to find further than $N_4$. The overall procedure remains what I have described above.

Comment: It’s a very good explanation, however it’s wrong to say that 222444 divides the next number.

Comment: This is going to find the next lowest number that is divisible by 222444, not just plain old 2004 ! Can you please correct it? The approach is great, though.

Comment: Ah, I was supposed to do the analysis by 2004. Although the procedure remains the same.